# Abstract class method declaration

Tags: php, oop

I just wrote code like this:

```
<?php
class test
{
// Force Extending class to define this method
abstract protected function getValue();
abstract protected function prefixValue($prefix);

// Common method
public function printOut() {
    print $this->getValue() . "\n";
}
}
class testabs extends test{

public function getValue()
{

}
public function prefixValue($f)
{

}
}
$obj = new testabs();
?>
```

When I run this code, I received the error below:

> Fatal error: Class test contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract **or implement the remaining methods (test::getValue, test::prefixValue)** in C:\wamp64\www\study\abstract.php on line 12

I understand the first part of this error. I changed the class test to abstract and the error is gone, but the `or` part i can't understand.

Comment: The _or_ part is from the point of view where a class extends your `test` class. It goes both ways; either make your `test` class abstract _or_ make any other class extending `test` abstract for they do not implement any of the inherited abstract declarations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are going to add abstract methods, then you will need to make the class `abstract` as well. That way, the class cannot be instantiated- only non-abstract sub-classes can be.

The method [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) (refer to the second sub-section [*Method Visiblilty*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods)) is not the same in the sub-class. Depending on whether you want the methods to be called by code outside of sub-classes, you can declare the (abstract) methods in class `test` with visibility `public`, or else declare the sub-class methods also with visibility `protected`.

And note the second paragraph from the [Class Abstraction page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), which explains this:

> When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child; additionally, these methods must be defined with the same (or a less restricted) visibility. For example, if the abstract method is defined as protected, the function implementation must be defined as either protected or public, but not private

```
<?php
abstract class test{
    // Force Extending class to define this method
    abstract protected function getValue();
    abstract protected function prefixValue($prefix);

    // Common method
    public function printOut() {
        print $this->getValue() . "\n";
    }
}
class testabs extends test{

    protected function getValue()
    {

    }
    /**
    *   this method can be called from other methods with this class 
    *   or sub-classes, but not called directly by code outside of this       class
    **/
    protected function prefixValue($f)
    {

    }
}
$obj = new testabs();
// this method cannot be called here because its visibility is protected
$obj->prefixValues();// Fatal Error
?>
```

Comment: Okay I updated my answer- see the new first paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

The key technical differences between an **abstract class** and an **interface** are:

- Abstract classes can have constants, members, method stubs (methods without a body) and defined methods, whereas interfaces can only have constants and methods stubs.
- Methods and members of an abstract class can be defined with any visibility, whereas all methods of an interface must be defined as public (they are defined public by default).
- When inheriting an abstract class, a concrete child class must define the abstract methods, whereas an abstract class can extend another abstract class and abstract methods from the parent class don't have to be defined.
- Similarly, an interface extending another interface is not responsible for implementing methods from the parent interface. This is because interfaces cannot define any implementation.
- A child class can only extend a single class (abstract or concrete), whereas an interface can extend or a class can implement multiple other interfaces.
- A child class can define abstract methods with the same or less restrictive visibility, whereas a class implementing an interface must define the methods with the exact same visibility (public).

Answer (score 2):

Your class has abstract functions but is not declared as abstract, so you have two choices. Either declare the class as `abstract` or provide an implementation of the abstract functions.

The first option (which you tried) allows the class to exist and be used by a concrete subclass that implements the functions. The second option means that the class is fully defined and can be used as is.

Answer (score 0):

When your `class` has `abstract` methods it has to be declared `abstract` too.
So the following is correct:

```
<?php
abstract class test
{
  // Force Extending class to define this method
  abstract protected function getValue();
  abstract protected function prefixValue($prefix);

  // Common method
  public function printOut() {
    print $this->getValue() . "\n";
  }
}
```